# Test the convergence of the series with alternating signs

Tags: sequences-and-series

The series is given by ($a>0$)

$$\frac{1}{a} +\frac{1}{a+1} - \frac{1}{a+2} +\frac{1}{a+3} +\frac{1}{a+4} -\frac{1}{a+5} +\cdots$$

So how can I move forward? I  can not find the general term  of the series. If someone can give the general term then I can go further.

Comment: Try $\frac{1}{a}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{a+n}$

Comment: Originally I thought that QC_QAOA's comment was on point, re https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test.  However, either their is a typo in the actual posting, or this is not a true alternating series (in the conventional sense), since the terms seem to run + + - + + - ...

Comment: Do the signs always go $++-$? I reckon that because of the imbalance of signs, if you collect batches of three terms together, then you'll get a series like $\sum 1/n$

Comment: My (**unproven**) intuition is that if there is no typo then the series is divergent.  I am basing this intuition on : (1) if you ignore all but the 1st, 4th, 7th, ... terms, then the series seems very similar to the harmonic series, which I know to be divergent :: and (2) the 2nd term - the 3rd term is > 0.  This pattern repeats re the 5th term - 6th term > 0 ...

Comment: Yes.you state correctly. This is not a properly alternative series.

Comment: But  the original question is correct.

Comment: If the original question is correct, then I think my previous note can be used as a guide to proving that the series diverges.

Comment: The  alternation of the terms  are    + + - + + -.....

Comment: Right, therefore the series diverges.

Comment: Please give the general term and a clear prrof

Comment: @maa you can follow the hint in user2661923's second comment to create a proof.

Comment: Previously given general term seems to be not correct to me  as you can verify by seeing the original series and the general term

Comment: @user2661923 this does not necessarily mean the series diverges. This is an example of the [Riemann rearrangement theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem)

Comment: I think @ninad is stating correct

Comment: @user is just saying  ti delete the 1st ,4th,7th term and make the general term as 1/a+n  +1/a+(n+1)       then the harmonic series  and comparision test will do the rest.Am i correct???

Comment: I upvoted from -2 to -1.  I agree that the OP hasn't shown work.  However, he may have done work, but not shown it, re his moderate language difficulties.  Also, his reference to the "general term of the series" suggests that he is moderately lost.  Therefore, I think that downvoting is overly harsh here.

Comment: @user2661923 you're right, this problem should not be so heavily downvoted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am editing this response to make it more readable and to incorporate the analysis in the comments posted subsequent to this response.

Let $s_n$ denote the nth term (i.e. $s_1 = 1/a$).

The proof is in two parts:
(1) showing that $s_1 + s_4 + s_7 + \cdots$ diverges.
(2) showing that as a result of (1) above, the overall series is divergent.

Fact: the harmonic series is known to be divergent.

(1)
Let M be a positive integer > a. 
Let R = $s_1 + s_4 + s_7 + \cdots.$ 
Let S = 1/M + 1/(M+3) + 1/(M+6) + ... 
Let T = 1/M + 1/(M+1) + 1/(M+2) + ...

Then R > S and 3S > T.

Further, since the harmonic series is divergent and since T is the same
as the harmonic series, with a finite group of terms excluded, T is
divergent.  Therefore, S is divergent.  Therefore R is divergent.

(2)
Since $(s_2 + s_3) > 0, (s_5 + s_6) > 0, \cdots$ 
it is immediate that $(s_1 + s_2 + s_3) + (s_4 + s_5 + s_6) + \cdots >
s_1 + s_4 + s_7 + \cdots = R,$ 
which was shown to be divergent in part (1).

**Addendum**: response to maa's comment below
First of all, my knowledge of convergent/divergent series in Real Analysis **is** somewhat limited, so I could well be mistaken.  However, I've checked my analysis and I don't see any flaw.

Based on the comment that I am responding to, it looks like the analysis in part (1) is being accepted and the analysis in part (2) is being questioned.

It also seems like the following intermediate conclusions in part (2) are being accepted.  If not, please advise.
$(s_1 + s_2 + s_3) > s_1$ 
$(s_4 + s_5 + s_6) > s_4$ 
$(s_7 + s_8 + s_9) > s_7$ 
$\cdots$

Define a new notation:
Let $b_1 \equiv (s_1 + s_2 + s_3).$
Let $b_2 \equiv (s_4 + s_5 + s_6).$
Let $b_3 \equiv (s_7 + s_8 + s_9).$
$\cdots$

Now contrast the following two infinite sums:
$s_1 + s_2 + s_3 + s_4 + s_5 + s_6 + s_7 + s_8 + s_9 + \cdots\;\;$ and 
$b_1 + b_2 + b_3 + \cdots.$

Notice that the 2nd infinite sum (above) **duplicates** the exact order that the terms occur in in the 1st infinite sum (above).  Therefore, the 1st infinite sum (above) will be divergent if and only if the 2nd infinite sum above is divergent.
**Edit** 
I imagine that it is possible to provide a counter-example to the analysis directly above.  For instance, a series that looks like:
$(0 +5 -5) + (0 +5 -5) + (0 +5 -5) + (0 +5 -5) + \cdots.$
However, I don't think that such a bizarre counter-example is relevant here.  
Remember, in the original series, $|s_n|$ is **strictly decreasing** and goes to zero.

**Edit-2nd**
Also, in the analysis below, the result I really need is that 
**if** $b_1 + b_2 + b_3 + \cdots$ is a divergent series 
**then** so is $s_1 + s_2 + s_3 + \cdots.$
I am having a hard time imagining a counter-example where this **one-way** implication breaks down.

Now consider the following two infinite sums:
$s_1 + s_4 + s_7 + \cdots \;\;$ and 
$b_1 + b_2 + b_3 + \cdots .$

From the previous analysis we know that:
$s_1 + s_4 + s_7 + \cdots$ is a divergent series 
$b_1 > s_1$ 
$b_2 > s_4$ 
$b_3 > s_7$ 
$\cdots$

Therefore, $b_1 + b_2 + b_3 + \cdots$ is a divergent series.
Therefore, $s_1 + s_2 + s_3 + s_4 + s_5 + s_6 + s_7 + s_8 + s_9 + \cdots$ is a divergent series.

Comment: This kind of argument of comparing some terms and adding things in different orders generally is not valid, because it requires knowing ahead of time that the series is not conditionally convergent. If a series is conditionally convergent, then changing the order of summation could make it diverge.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I'm not actually changing the order of the terms.  Let $s_n$ denote the nth term (i.e. $s_1 = 1/a.)$  Then it is immediate that $(s_1 + s_2 + s_3) + (s_4 + s_5 + s_6) + \cdots > s_1 + s_4 + s_7 + \cdots.$

Comment: ah okay, I understand it better now - I think this is okay. If you could just make the answer look TeX, I will upvote it.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Good point re readability.  I edited the answer.

Comment: @ninad munsi  i can  not undestand the process of you.how  can you state that the general term is that you written?

Comment: I don't think you're responding to the right person

Comment: @maa Are you addressing me re difficulty understanding my response.  If so, are you asking me for further explanation in my answer re part (1), part (2), or both? Also, it will help me answer your question if you can pinpoint the specific step that I took which you are not sure is valid.

Comment: To whoever downvoted my answer: is there a flaw in my analysis?

Comment: Hello  Ninad Munshi, i am speaking to you.listen carefully my problem:         how can you find the general term by just  writing it. I need further explanation  about the choosing your general term.

Comment: Hello user2661923 ,sorry i  failed to understand the procedure of you.please forgive me.I will respond your method few hour later after showing it properly.Thanks

Comment: Hello  ninad , you  are taking three terms as a single term for making the series positive .How you can do this.I think you should look into it  again.

Comment: @maa Please see the addendum to my answer.  Does this resolve your issues re my analysis?  If not, please advise.  Also, to anyone else reading this, please advise if you still have issues re my analysis.

Answer (score 3):

Rewrite the series as

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{a+n-1}+\frac{1}{a+n}-\frac{1}{a+n+1} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(a+n)^2+2(a+n)-1}{(a+n)^3-(a+n)}$$

which diverges by limit comparison test to $\frac{1}{n}$